# Merging a .csv file with a .shp file in R

Tags: shapefile, r, csv, merge

I am trying to merge a .csv file with a .shp file. The shapefile has more information that I need so I also want to limit it by only adding information for the counties in my csv file. I tried my code based on a response to a similar question posted here but received an error. Once I merge them, I would like to make it a shapefile. Here is my code:

```
library(raster)

county_info <- read.csv("/path/county_info.csv")
county_shape <- readShapePoly("/path/county_shape.shp")
data <- merge(county_info, county_shape, by="GEOID", all.x=TRUE)
data <- shapefile(data, "/path")
```

The error I receive is:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘shapefile’ for signature ‘"data.frame"’
```

Comment: Without giving an answer to your problem, I advise you to switch to the sf package for vector handling. Much more fun

Answer (score 3):

As aldo_tapia suggests, sf is a great improvement upon the foundation of sp. I would comment if my reputation permitted it.

As for learning sf, the entire Geocomputation with R textbook is available online at https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/. Everything makes a lot of sense from a traditional R dataframe perspective, and it is dplyr compliant.

That being said, if you are deadset on using sp, you could always access the associated data with county_shape@data, and then merge with your csv. It's ugly and error-prone, but I've definitely done it in the past.

```
library(raster)

county_info <- read.csv("/path/county_info.csv")
county_shape <- readShapePoly("/path/county_shape.shp")


county_shape@data <- merge(county_info, county_shape@data, by="GEOID", all.x=TRUE)
```

That being said, learn sf instead of you have the time. Someone else can probably explain in detail why the above is a bad idea!

Answer (score 1):

Laura, as Bernd V. suggested, you can use `sf` for vector management. In this case, use it with `dplyr` for merging different objects:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

county_info <- read.csv("/path/county_info.csv")
county_shape <- read_sf("/path/county_shape.shp")
county_info %>% full_join(y = county_shape, by = 'GEOID') %>%
                st_as_sf() %>%
                write_sf("/path/output.shp")
```

There are different merging methods, like `inner_join`, `left_join`, `full_join`, and so on. Check `dplyr` package documentation for more info.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried your suggestion but received about another error: 
Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") : no applicable method for 'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('SpatialPolygonsDataFrame', 'SpatialPolygons', 'Spatial', 'SpatialVector')"
Do you know why this is?

Comment: That raised up because you're using a sp object, not a sf object. You can convert it with `st_as_sf` or load it with `read_sf` function